# Getting this message app.js:33 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null at HTMLButtonElement.addTodo

Tags: appendchild

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMx0b.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7S8c.png)

I had to initially put the  behind the body because it was refreshing the page. 
Now i'm running into this error "app.js:33 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null
    at HTMLButtonElement.addTodo"

Comment: Hello, and welcome, can you share the code in text and not in images please ?

Answer (score 0):

Your selector is `.todo-List`, yet all your other class names don't use any upper-case characters, and your HTML shows `class="todo-list"` (`list`, not `List`!) as well.

So, I'd assume that this is a typo and should actually be `todo-list` with lower-case `l`, so you should change the line 4 to `const todoList = document.querySelector('.todo-list')`.

The fact that you asked about the "message" of `Cannot read property "appendChild" of null` though sounds to me as if you didn't understand the error message. Please take the time to review [this article](https://idiallo.com/javascript/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-of-null) and take a quick squiz at [how to use a debugger](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x4q86IjJFag). Especially the latter is a tremendously important skill that will help you trace back those issues yourself. I'm sure, had you realized that the issues comes from line 4, you'd eventually have discovered that the selector is wrong.